# Excel: dynamically calculate range next to a searched up cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, range

I am an occasional Excel user and stuck how to create a dynamic range.

After looking up a text in a table, how can I calculate the range next to this cell, up to the next empty row? Not using VBA.

[image]

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `H4`, formula copied down :

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDEX(C:C,MATCH(F4,A:A,0)):C$1000,MATCH(G4,INDEX(B:B,MATCH(F4,A:A,0)):B$1000,0)),"")
```

[image]

Should you want a **dynamic range**,

Change `C$1000` to `INDEX(C:C,MATCH(9.9E+307,B:B)`

and

Change `B$1000` to `INDEX(B:B,MATCH(9.9E+307,B:B))`

Then

The `H4` copied down formula become :

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDEX(C:C,MATCH(F4,A:A,0)):INDEX(C:C,MATCH(9.9E+307,B:B)),MATCH(G4,INDEX(B:B,MATCH(F4,A:A,0)):INDEX(B:B,MATCH(9.9E+307,B:B)),0)),"")
```

**Edit :**

As per  Ron Rosenfeld's comment, "should B11 change to 24 and G4 change to 24"

The "Source Table" set up in **Excel Table** type for dynamic range growing purpose

and

The `H4` formula change to :

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(9^9,Table1[price]/(LOOKUP(ROW(Table1[texture]),ROW(Table1[texture])/(Table1[texture]<>""),Table1[texture])=F4)/(Table1[length]=G4)),"")
```

[image]

Comment: If a texture below the target texture has a length that is not present in the target, your formula will return the wrong answer.  Eg,  Change `B11: 24` and `G4:24`. Your formula will return `190` in `H4` vice error

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld, thanks for your advice and the post edited in accordingly with a new formula proposal.

Comment: Nice use of LOOKUP.

Comment: Bounding the range to a target texture (up to the empty row) was my problem, as @ron-rosenfeld pointed out. Doing multiple intersections is a nice solution and works for me, thx.

Comment: One thing to watch out for are "orphaned" price blocks, not having a texture label. Also when having another following block with the same label. The lookup will grab the price from this block. The solution does not take the first block and bounds the block till the empty row. Having correct unique data is key. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Combining the `Index()` and `Match()` functions usually works well when using two conditions. However, you will need to fill out the entire column A with the "texture" list in order for the below formula to work.

```
=INDEX(<P1>, MATCH(TRUE, (<T1>=<T2>) + (<L1>=<L2>) > 1,0))
```

- Where `<P1>` is your entire price column (ex. `C2:C15`)
- Where `<T1>` is your entire texture column (ex. `A2:A15`)
- Where `<T2>` is your texture lookup value cell
- Where `<L1>` is your entire length column (ex. `B2:B15`)
- Where `<L2>` is your length lookup value cell

---

Let's say that you input your texture value into cell `F3`, and your length value into cell `F4`. With the remaining columns remaining as they are in your image, you would use the following formula:

```
=INDEX(C2:C15, MATCH(TRUE, (A2:A15=F3) + (B2:B15=F4) > 1,0))
```

[image]

---

Now last time I had to use Index/Match I thought I had to place the formula into an array. However, the above seems to work without it.

If you notice that it's not working as expected, you can place into an array formula by clicking the cell that contains the formula, then clicking the formula box at the top. While in the formula box, simultaneously press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Return</kbd>. This should then place curly brackets around your entire formula if done properly, as such:

[image]

Comment: I am using latest Excel, not O365. I adapted the texture column as needed for this solution. Unfortunately I always receive an NA. I used F9 debug, for the MATCH I received the correct number, reducing to INDEX(C2:C15, number) the answer was correct. Your original formula throws an NA. With debugging I understood what the >1 does, the intersection of the two matched ranges have a value of 2, which gets converted to a boolean and matched against TRUE. Any thoughts why a reduced formula works, but the complete formula does not?

Answer (score 0):

If you have O365 with the `SEQUENCE` function, you can use, for price:

```
=IF(G4="","",VLOOKUP(G4,INDEX($B:$C,SEQUENCE(MATCH(TRUE,ISBLANK(INDEX($B:$B,MATCH(F4,$A:$A,0)):INDEX(B:B,ROWS(B:B)-MATCH(F4,$A:$A,0))),0)-1,,MATCH(F4,$A:$A,0)),{1,2}),2,FALSE))
```

[image]

explanation:

- get starting row:

  ```
  MATCH(F4,$A:$A,0)
  ```
- ending row will be the first blank row after the starting row:

  ```
  MATCH(TRUE,ISBLANK(INDEX($B:$B,MATCH(F4,$A:$A,0)):INDEX(B:B,ROWS(B:B)-MATCH(F4,$A:$A,0))),0)
  ```
- Construct the relevant array:

  ```
  INDEX($B:$C,SEQUENCE(MATCH(TRUE,ISBLANK(INDEX($B:$B,MATCH(F4,$A:$A,0)):INDEX(B:B,ROWS(B:B)-MATCH(F4,$A:$A,0))),0)-1,,MATCH(F4,$A:$A,0)),{1,2})
  ```

  - The above might reduce (with `wavy`) to:

    ```
      index(b:c,{9,10,11},{1,2}
    ```

Then it's just a matter of applying the `VLOOKUP`

A more understandable, but longer with more operations, formula available in O365 makes use of `LET`. The advantage is that one can use names which indicate what each section of the formula does.

For example:

```
=IF(G4="","",LET(startRow,MATCH(F4,$A:$A,0),numRows,MATCH(TRUE,ISBLANK(INDEX($B:$B,startRow):INDEX($B:$B,ROWS($B:$B)-startRow)),0)-1,
       arr,INDEX($B:$C,SEQUENCE(numRows,,startRow),{1,2}),price,XLOOKUP(G4,INDEX(arr,0,1),INDEX(arr,0,2)),price))
```

Or, using `VLOOKUP`

```
=IF(G4="","",VLOOKUP(G4,LET(startRow,MATCH(F4,$A:$A,0),numRows,MATCH(TRUE,ISBLANK(INDEX($B:$B,startRow):INDEX($B:$B,ROWS($B:$B)-startRow)),0)-1,arr,INDEX($B:$C,SEQUENCE(numRows,,startRow),{1,2}),arr),2,FALSE))
```

Finally, for earlier versions of Excel, you can use this whopper where we replace the `SEQUENCE` function with a construct like: `ROW(INDEX(A:A,firstRow):INDEX(A:A,lastRow))`

```
=IF(G4="","",VLOOKUP(G4,INDEX($B:$C,ROW(INDEX($A:$A,MATCH(F4,$A:$A,0)):INDEX($A:$A,MATCH(F4,$A:$A,0)+MATCH(TRUE,INDEX($B:$B,MATCH(F4,$A:$A,0)):INDEX($B:$B,ROWS($B:$B))="",0)-2)),{1,2}),2,FALSE))
```

Comment: Just curious Ron, when constructing a formula specifically for O365, rather than using  VLookup why not use XLookup with its greater flexibility and performance?

Comment: @chrisneilsen In this particular formula, I chose not to because I didn't want to duplicate constructing the dynamic range (for lookup_array and return_array).  Of course, I could have also used `LET` to get around that, but I was thinking that if O365 was not an option, it would be easier to replace the `SEQUENCE` function than the rest.  But right now, I'm working on a construction using `LET`. But I got called away.

Comment: @chrisneilsen I posted a version using LET and XLOOKUP, but I prefer the VLOOKUP version for this particular setup (at least using my approach) -- shorter and fewer operations.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have latest Excel, not O365, so haven't took a deeper look into your solution.

Comment: @FritzHerbers I have added a formula that can be used in earlier versions of Excel, by replacing the `SEQUENCE` function with a longer formula that does the same.